# How to convert this Query to Laravel Eloquent or Using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm developing an app using laravel framework, just wanted to ask how to convert this mysql query to Laravel Eloquent or Laravel Query Builder. Please advise.

```
SELECT * FROM skill_user AS su, skills AS s WHERE su.user_id = 1 AND su.skill_id = s.id
```

Here's my query so far

```
$skills = DB::table('skill_user')
                    ->where('skill_user.user_id','=', $profile_id)
                    ->where('skill_user.skill_id', '=', 'skills.id')
                    ->get();
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to convert the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In User model which extends from eloquent add a function:

```
public function skills() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Skill');
}
```

Your Skill model must extend from eloquent too.

Now you can select your User with the skill data:

```
$user = User::with('skills')->find(1);
```

you can receive the skill data with:

```
$user->skills
```